# F#: I cannot return unit in a do clause and still have side effects

Tags: object, f#, initialization, unit-type

I'm writing a simple ini file parser and I'm having a little problem with the initialization of the object in the "do" clause. It wants me to return a unit but i can't get the blankity function to do the side effects if I try to pipe into an "ignore" or if i return "()" directly.

This code works as a separate function because I *can* ignore the results.

```
#light

module Utilities.Config

open System
open System.IO
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
open System.Collections.Generic

type Config(?fileName : string) =
    let fileName = defaultArg fileName @"C:\path\myConfigs.ini"

    static let defaultSettings =
        dict[ "Setting1", "1";
              "Setting2", "2";
              "Debug",    "0";
              "State",    "Disarray";]

    let settingRegex = new Regex(@"\s*(?<key>([^;#=]*[^;#= ]))\s*=\s*(?<value>([^;#]*[^;# ]))")
    let fileSettings = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    let addFileSetting (groups : GroupCollection) =
        fileSettings.Add(groups.Item("key").Value, groups.Item("value").Value)

    do  File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
        |> Seq.map(fun line -> settingRegex.Match(line))
        |> Seq.filter(fun mtch -> mtch.Success)
        |> Seq.map(fun mtch -> addFileSetting(mtch.Groups) // Does not have the correct return type
        //|> ignore //#1 Does not init the dictionary
        //()        //#2 Does not init the dictionary

    //The extra step will work
    member c.ReadFile =
        File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
        |> Seq.map(fun line -> settingRegex.Match(line))
        |> Seq.filter(fun mtch -> mtch.Success)
        |> Seq.map(fun mtch -> addFileSetting(mtch.Groups))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Seq.iter` (executing an action for each element - returning `unit`) instead of `Seq.map` (transforming elements).

The code doesn't work with `ignore` because `Seq`'s are evaluated lazily and when you ignore the result, there is no need to run any code at all. [Read this article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Sequences)